# How can I get the entity a player is looking at in a Bukkit plugin?

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding, bukkit

I'm creating a wizardry plugin for Minecraft, and I was wondering how you would get the entity that a player was looking at, I know that you would have to use a `Vector`, but I really am not familiar with them. Pretty much what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
public void entityLookingAt(Player p){
    if(p.EntityLookingAt() instanceof Player){
        p.sendMessage("You're looking at a player!");
    }
}
```

Comment: While not off topic, mod questions don't get a lot of traction here. You might want to ask at the forums for Bukkit or Minecraft.

Comment: @Byte56 I do not believe that this is a duplicate, as this is asking how to do it using the bukkit API, the other question is asking how to do it with the Minecraft API

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Domenico He didn't say it was a duplicate, he was just trying to say that this isn't the best place to ask for modding help because you may not get a lot of answers :)

Comment: @AidanMueller He marked it as duplicate a while ago :)

Comment: @Domenico Oh I see now.